# Config Subdomain to point to heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain, heroku

I have to host a subdomain of my domain to heroku app. For example abc.com points to a Hostgator account. I want to configure app.abc.com to heroku app.
The domain is registered with godaddy.
Can anyone please help me out.

Regards
Avinasha

Comment: Has nothing to do with programming other than you mentioning a hosting provider tailored for rails.

Comment: Configuring your server settings isn't really programming, so I've voted to move this question to ServerFault, the site for, well, this :)

Comment: This is actually a heroku-specific question as you can see in the answers containing links to their documentation on how to do just this.

Comment: @tfe — it's still little to do with programming, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd actually point to a different part of that page:

[What IP addresses should I use to point my custom domain at Heroku?](http://docs.heroku.com/faq-product-features#what-ip-addresses-should-i-use-to-point-my-custom-domain-at-heroku)

Create a CNAME record in your DNS settings pointing `subdomain` to `proxy.heroku.com`.

The wildcard domains section has to do with pointing *any* subdomain the user provides to your Heroku app; these instructions are for a single subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but still ranking pretty high when I was looking at a solution for a similar problem.

The heroku docs you're looking for is the one on [Custom Domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains).

For an old domain from NameCheap, with CPanel-backed hosting from them, I used those instructions to successfully point a subdomain to a rails app hosted on heroku.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go: [Can I point *.mydomain.com to my Heroku app?](http://docs.heroku.com/faq-product-features#can-i-point-mydomaincom-to-my-heroku-app)

Comment: Outdated: dead link