# Host subdomain on heroku

Tags: domain-name-system, heroku

What is the simplest answer to host a subdomain (only, not the main domain) on Heroku?

I tried question [Config Subdomain to point to heroku app](https://serverfault.com/questions/184185/config-subdomain-to-point-to-heroku-app) but the Heroku KB pages it points to are gone (404)

For my specific case, I want to point dev.example.com to Heroku

I do not have direct access to the DNS for example.com, it is managed by an IT person. I want to get it right the first time because it takes days for their IT person to update the DNS.

So, would it be my-app-name.heroku.com for a CNAME or proxy.heroku.com ? or something else?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but since Heroku is getting money from you why not ask them for an authoritative answer?

Comment: That's not rude, but not quite correct either. I haven't given them any money, and there are many other questions on here about Heroku, just following the trend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper thing to do here is CNAME your subdomain to proxy.heroku.com.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thank you! It wasn´t quite clear from their support kb whether I needed an A record or a CNAME for a subdomain only situation.